# What is the difference between using index.js and MyComponent.vue as entry points?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

So I was comparing the source code of javascript libraries uploaded on npm.
Both projects uses Vue, but there are some differences:

1. The first code uses `index.js` as its entry points and it globally registers the component by using:

   ```
   import component from './foo.vue'

   const plugin = {
     install: Vue => {
       Vue.component(component.name, component)
     }
   }

   component.install = plugin.install

   export default component
   ```
2. The second one instead immediately uses the `.vue` file as entry point

My questions are:

1. what are the difference between using `index.js` and `.vue` file as entry point?
2. what does the install at `component.install` do?

Comment: `component.install` is very likely a [plugin installation method](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin). Can you share the npm projects that you found so that we can get clearer context?

Comment: @YongQuan here https://github.com/kevinongko/vue-instagram, https://github.com/eddyerburgh/vue-digital-clock